# Lang in laravel not work in controller from ajax return to view

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

lang multi Language in laravel not work in controller.I use ajax query database in Controller,I need to use lang in controller return to view but output not translate Language such as

### controller

```
public function a2($id)
{
echo '<h1>'.@lang('home.text').'</h1>';
echo '<p>content from query data</p>';
}
```

### ajax

```
success: function (data) {
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data;       
}
```

### html

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

### output

> @lang('home.text')
>   content from query data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lang() is for blade, use __()

```
public function a2($id)
{
    echo '<h1>'.__('home.text').'</h1>';
    echo '<p>content from query data</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`__`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#retrieving-translation-strings) helper function in controllers:

```
public function a2($id)
{
    echo '<h1>'. __('home.text').'</h1>';
    echo '<p>content from query data</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
Lang::get('home.text')
```

instead of

```
@lang('home.text')
```

Comment: Lang::get('home.text') is Successful
Thankyou very much